# CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX does not respect 'target_include_directories' when looking for include file

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build [simple-web-server](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server) using a local standalone copy of [asios](https://think-async.com/Asio/). As I don't have the library installed, and I can't install it due to security restrictions, I've modified the cmakelists file just a bit, to tell it where to search for the include file. I can clearly see that it's finding the location, but `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX` isn't finding it for some reason, even though I've added the directory with `target_include_directories`. What is the correct way to do this?

```
if(USE_STANDALONE_ASIO)

### BEGIN CUSTOM ADDITIONS ###

    message(NOTICE "Searching for asio.hpp")
    find_path(ASIO_PATH asio.hpp ./asio/include) 
    if(ASIO_PATH-NOTFOUND)
        message(AUTHOR_WARNING "Asio not found in ./asio/include")
    else()
        message(NOTICE "asio.hpp found in ${ASIO_PATH}")
        target_include_directories(simple-web-server INTERFACE ASIO_PATH)
    endif()

### END CUSTOM ADDITIONS ###    

    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(simple-web-server INTERFACE ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    
   target_include_directories
        target_compile_definitions(simple-web-server INTERFACE USE_STANDALONE_ASIO)
        include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
        CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(asio.hpp HAVE_ASIO)
        if(NOT HAVE_ASIO)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Standalone Asio not found")
        endif()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `target_include_directories` and `include_directories` affects on **compilation**, but doesn't affect on **checking** headers via `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX`.

For hint the macro `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX` to search in additional include directories, set variable `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES ${ASIO_PATH})
...
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(asio.hpp HAVE_ASIO)
```

This variable is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFileCXX.html):

> `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`
>
> a list of header search paths to pass to the compiler.

---

While internally `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX` performs compilation, it compiles in **other CMake project** (via [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html)). That other project doesn't receive properties (like `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`) of the main project. Instead, a specific set of variables is explicitly passed from the main project, and `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` is among that variables.