# In CMake, get all the include search paths in check_include_file_cxx

Tags: cmake

I want to check the self-sufficiency of all my headers in my C++ project managed with CMake. Using `check_include_file_cxx` I am partially able to do it, except that some include file are missing and false negatives are reported.

The solution in [CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX does not respect 'target_include_directories' when looking for include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300495/check-include-file-cxx-does-not-respect-target-include-directories-when-lookin) involves manually adding the required directories.

I would like to instead transfer all the search path used during any normal compilation in my project to `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`. Is it possible and how ?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the search path used during any normal compilation"? Because of `target_*` commands different files can be compiled with **different search paths**. Moreover, the paths added via `target_include_directories` are processed by CMake only **at the end** of the configuration process (because those paths may contain [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)). You cannot ask CMake to resolve that paths during configuration, when `check_include_file_cxx` is executed.

Comment: I would like to avoid manually filling `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES` as proposed in the linked post, considering that all the information has already been provided through calls to `include_directories` for example.

Comment: The command [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) adds directories to the directory property [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html). So you may extract directories from that property by using e.g. `get_property` command.